# How can I get difference between two pandas dataframes having different index values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`.
`df1` has values for A, B, C and D.
`df2` has values for B, C, D and E.

`df1.to_dict()` returns

```
{'Value': {'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 6, 'D': 6}}
```

`df2.to_dict()` returns

```
{'Value': {'B': 4, 'C': 2, 'D': 6, 'E': 8}}
```

I want to get difference between `df1` and `df2`.
While doing `df1-df2`, I get nan values for A and E respectively.

I want to get the difference such that I still get value for A by considering 0 value for A in `df2` and getting value for E by considering 0 value for B in `df1`.
How can this be programmed?

Comment: `df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)`